Reduce [Questions with no answers]
At this moment there are 3,205,054 questions with no answers
I'm sure half or more of these questions have been answered in the comments

While there is no way to force OP to answer by themself,
I'd if there is an option or a filter like:

Mark a question as Have an answer in the comment

to reduce its priority and allow answers focus on other questions without a replay

If you're sure that a comment answers the question, you could always write an answer that includes the comment text and credits the original author.

"What is the solution for that?" What is the problem with that?

@RobertLongson, do you mean just a quote for that comment ?

Go write some answers. I'd hazard a guess a very sizable chunk of them are simply no longer relevant. Old problems, or problems only relevant to the asker, etc. If you're looking for things to answer, an answer existing in the comments isn't a reason to not post an answer.

@vandench, the problem is, you open a question and read it carfully tring to collect information to answer it, after that you notice OP found the answer in the comment

Why is a comment existing preventing you from posting an answer? Answers aren't meant only for the OP.

@KevinB, rather than write an answer for the one who already fixed his issue, I prefer to find a new one waiting for an answer, later on I can back to that to write an answer. priority wise

then you should only look at recent questions.

"I'm sure half or more of these questions have been answered in the comments" - no they haven't. Comments are not answers, it is SO law. For one there isn't nearly enough space in a comment to hold a proper answer. At best questions are partially answered in comments. I can venture a guess that you are building a wall for yourself here preventing you from posting answers because you want to throw honesty / honour into the mix. That is not how Stack Overflow works. If someone posts a comment instead of answering, it is their own responsibility they missed out on some internet points.

@Gimby, You and everyone who COMMENT here is greatly appreciated, DownVote without a COMMENT is ignored on my side and not counted, this topic is realy annoying me and I will reopend it soon with new updates, taking your COMMENTS in consideration

I generally agree, that there's a lot of questions out there that have comment answers that should either be properly answered or deleted by roomba... but that's more a question of where we draw the line. 1.8million of those 3.2million are zero scored... but that's a lot of questions to arbitrarily delete that aren't otherwise causing a known problem.
There's no value in marking questions as "answered improperly", unless to encourage people to answer them properly.
